Build failed due to use of deleted Android v1 embedding in Flutter
I am going to build flutter project, but it shows following error.
flutter run

Error: Build failed due to use of deleted Android v1 embedding.
I tried to clean flutter and pub get and upgarde, but it doesn't works well.
Should I downgrade my flutter version or Android SDK?
What steps can be taken to resolve the build failure caused by the removal of the Android v1 embedding?
Further, I want to know why this problem is happened though upgraded?
(My flutter version is 3.24.0, Android SDK is 34)

You need to change the android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml file.
Change this :
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    ...

To :
<application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        ...

.
.
.
And also add this lines if they don't exist :
From this:
<meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />

To this
<meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
          ...

